# How to have a Touch Bar button which is image only?

Tags: swift, macos, macos-sierra, nstouchbar

Adding touch bar buttons into touch bar of macOS, with images of size 80x60, ends up like this:

[image: Touch Bar with buttons]

The button has been scaled to 40x30, but instead of a button filled up by image, it has the left/right padding on the side of button. Is it possible to have actual size of touch bar buttons without the padding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use **Image Button** from object library, but you have to include it into the **Touch Bar View** which you can find in object library.

Output looks like this:

[image]